# MetalLB External IP via interface without any IP - can't add route with specific gateway

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, kubernetes

I have a cluster of dedicated servers physically connected to switch to which my housing provider routes several public IPv4 addresses in same /24 subnet (I am only allowed to use about 14 public IPv4 out of that subnet though).

My goal is to setup MetalLB on kubernetes cluster in a way that it handles public IP traffic from one specific IP (for example 207.120.238.23 (not really my IP) where gateway would be 207.120.238.1) across a number of worker nodes. So there would be a number of VMs, each with WAN NIC and they would all be load balancing traffic for single public IP.

My k8s cluster VMs have several network interfaces, first enX0 is for LAN communication and then there is a WAN interface (enX2) that is mapped to physical interface of each hypervisor to which the ISP internet uplink is connected to.

The reason why I want to do it like this is to save on public IPv4 addresses which are expensive, I want to avoid having to assign static public IPv4 address to every single k8s worker node and instead just have them serve the load-balanced MetalLB traffic for that one IPv4.

To achieve that, I purposefully didn't assign any IP to enX2 and just brought it up, here is my /etc/network/interfaces snippet

```
auto enX2
iface enX2 inet manual
  up ip link set dev $IFACE up
  down ip link set dev $IFACE down
```

Then I configured MetalLB to handle incoming traffic for that 207.120.238.23

Now it works, but only for incoming traffic. When I try to connect from internet to port 80 or 443 which MetalLB handles traffic for, the packet arrives on the public network interfaces and one of speaker daemons on k8s-workers with this public WAN interfaces processes it.

**But it can't send the response back** - because it doesn't really know how. It tries to send the packets back using primary default gateway, which is using LAN interface enX0 and completely different outgoing public IPv4.

I thought - easy, let's use source routing and set up a custom rule that all packets that are sent to 207.120.238.23 are processed using custom routing table that will tell it to use default route via 207.120.238.1 enX2.

But that doesn't work either - it seems kernel doesn't allow creating a route if you don't have an IP on interface:

```
# ip route add default via 207.120.238.1 dev enX2 table wan-route
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```

Is there any solution for this? Can it be done? It would have worked if I added a static public IPv4 to every single k8s worker node within same subnet, but that is prohibitively expensive and all those IPv4 wouldn't be useful for anything besides convincing the kernel it really is possible to use such route.

UPDATE: using "onlink" seems to work, now I successfully created default route on routing table wan-route that contains correct gateway, but using tcpdump I can still see that packets are arriving on enX2, but are replies are send via enX0.

This is the rules I set:

```
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32763:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup wan-route
32764:  from 207.120.238.23 lookup wan-route
32765:  from 207.120.238.23/24 lookup wan-route
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

I created also firewall mark using

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i enX2 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

to make sure that replies to packets from enX2 are sent out using enX2, but none of it is working, replies are still being sent out via enX0

Comment: I didn't understand your setup (a bit complex), but about the last command, just add the `onlink` parameter on it. Kernel doesn't allow to create a route referencing a gateway that has no route, which could become a chicken-n-egg problem, hence `onlink` to disable the check. No idea if that will solve your actual problem.

Comment: thanks, that indeed works, now I see the default route is there, but with tcpdump I can still see that incoming packets from internet come from enX2, but reply is sent out using enX0, I tried everything possible so far, including iptables packet marking to ensure that answer is sent out via enX2, but nothing seems to work :( I will update question with more details